# Laravel backup - Copying zip failed because: There is a connection error when trying to connect to disk named `S3`

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, amazon-s3, backup

I'm trying:

```
php artisan backup:run --only-db -vvv
```

But get an error with no detail as to what the issue could be:

> Copying zip failed because: There is a connection error when trying to connect to disk named `S3`

The `-vvv` doesn't seem to have any effect, how do I get more details for this error?
Or how would I debug this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sometimes the act of writing the question and actually pushing the Post button triggers some additional thinking even after one seems to have exhausted all avenues.

Case matters - my config/backup.php had an uppercase `S` and my config/filesystems.php had a lowercase `s` (the default).

Comment: The question on -vvv not giving any more details remains